# The 3-rd roots of $1$ are $1$ and $-\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.If $w \neq 1$ is a 5-th root show that it satisfies $w^4+w^3+w^2+w+1 = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I was thinking of using the fact that since $w$ is a 5-th root,then $w^5 = 1$ and then looking for other complex roots other than the principle root.
But when i did that I was getting $1+1+1+1+1$ which does not give me $0$.

Comment: By the way, you can find explicit expressions for the "other" fifth roots by rewriting the equation as $w^2+w+1+\frac{1}{w}+\frac{1}{w^2}=0$ nad making the substitution $w+\frac{1}{w}=t$.

Comment: I do not know what precisely you are suggesting. With the (standard) suggestion I made, we get a quadratic in $t$ with integer coefficients. We solve for $t$ explicitly, and the $w+\frac{1}{w}=t$ gives us another quadratic equation to solve. Slightly nicer in some ways is to let $w+\frac{1}{w}=2t$, but that's essentially the same idea.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$(1-w)(\sum_{r=0}^nw^r)=1-w^{n+1}$$

If $\displaystyle w\ne1$ and $\displaystyle w^{n+1}=1,\sum_{r=0}^nw^r=?$